# Regex to get a nth word from a string which is containing different words which are separated by semicolon(;)

Tags: regex, dynatrace

I have a string(Operation logging information) which is combination of different words and all are operated by semicolon(;). I want to extract the 23 word which are tell me the customer is eligible for the operation or Not.

I am new to regex, Could you please help me to find out the regex.
I am going to use this regex in **Dynatrace** tool where JAVA regex function will not work

String example 1:
`57423543521;314743352134;Source;Tue Apr 02 12:32:44 BST 2019;ELIGIBILITY;ABC345;MyChannel;DUMBRE;1;RR87835;NM;2019-04-02T07:20:00.000Z;VV;;;M;N;XCB234657;;24234SDF4435345;MrNitinDumbre;N;N;DFD4546;Adult;;MYTICKET;4535435435;;657657655;PP;N;Y;;Y;;N;;;Unconfirmed;;;Not Performed;OK;;Not Known`

===> the 23rd word in above the string is `'N'` (before the 'DFD4546;Adult', marked as **BOLD**)

String example 2:
`435435435435;345435435657;Source;Tue Apr 02 14:42:20 BST 2019;ELIGIBILITY;PQR490;MyChannel;DUMBRE;2;LK345029;CDGPNQ;2019-04-02T21:15:00.000Z;TT;;;W;Y;;N;34243DFGDFG32434;ProfNitin FDGDFDumbre;N;Y;;Adult;;MYTICKET;345435435;;;;N;Y;;Y;;N;Y;;Unconfirmed;;;Cleared;OK;;Not Known`

===> the 23rd word in above the string is `'Y'` (before the ';Adult'marked as **BOLD**)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to get exactly the 23rd word, and capture it from group1

```
(?:([^;]*);){23}
```

Here the outer non-grouping parenthesis matches zero or more any character except `;` using `[^;]*` followed by a `;` and whole of it matching exactly `23` times using `{23}` quantifier where last match gets captured in group 1 using `([^;]*)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0NRvCN/1)**

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh,

Its perfectly working fine!!

Will it be possible to extend the regex to identify the 23 word is **Y** or **N** ?

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: @NitinD: Sure we can do that. This regex `^(?:[^;]*;){22}Y;` will only match if 23rd word is Y and this regex `^(?:[^;]*;){22}N;` will only match if 23rd word is N. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Yes its working fine in Regex tester <br/><br/>
But when I used the same regex in **Dynatrace** it is not working<br/>
please find the attached screenshot.<br/>

[Dynatrace tool][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/phrV4.png

Comment: @NitinD: It says no group found for pattern. There are no groups in this regex but if you want a grouped version of regex, use this `^(?:[^;]*;){22}(Y);` for Y and `^(?:[^;]*;){22}(N);` for N

Comment: its perfectly working fine.

I have tried to **^(?:[^;]*;){22}(N);** regex to check whether the 17th OR 23th word is '**N**', but didn't find the feasible one. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: For making it work for either 17th or 23rd, you will need to use this regex `^(?:(?:[^;]*;){16}(N);|(?:[^;]*;){22}(N);)` This is for `N` and for `Y` just replace `N` with `Y` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0NRvCN/3)

Comment: Sorry Pushpesh, asking one more help.
Will it be possible to extend this  **^(?:[^;]*;){22}(Y);** to check  23rd work is  **'Y' AND** 35 word is **'N'** ?

Comment: @NitinD: Yes, sure it is pretty easy. You can use this regex `^(?:[^;]*;){22}(Y);(?:[^;]*;){11}(N);` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0NRvCN/4)

Comment: Will it be possible extract value of **24 word** if the value of **23 word** is **'N'**?